# Toggle boolean data/prop value of li element

Tags: vue.js

Here is a simplified version of my component.  I'm trying to toggle a checkmark if a language has been selected from the list, default to english. Currently they are all selected or all deselected.

```js
<template>
<ul>
    <li
        v-for="(subNavItem, index) in navItem.children"
        :key="index"
        @click="toggle(); selectLanguage(subNavItem.value)"
    >
        <a>                
            <span>
                {{ subNavItem.label }}
            </span>
            <span
                v-if="isEnabled"
                class="navMobile__list__item-icon-enabled"
            >
                <span class="icon icon--tick">
                    <svg class="icon-inner">                            
                        <use xlink:href="#tick" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {  
            selectedLocale: '',         
            isEnabled: false,
        };
    },  
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            locales: state => state.locales,
            localeLabels: state => state.localeLabels,
        }),
    },  
    methods: {  
        selectLanguage(locale) {
            const updatedQueryString = appendQueryString({ locale });
            window.location.search = updatedQueryString;
        },      
        toggle() {
            this.isEnabled = !this.isEnabled;
        },
    },    
};

</script>
```

These are my current props/data.

[image]
I think I need to make isEnabled a prop instead, and then I could change my v-if to:

```
v-if="subNavItem.isEnabled"
```

Does it make the most sense to do it this way? And if so how do I attach the isEnabled prop to the appropriate subNavItems?

Visual:

[image]

EDIT:
Okay I figured out how to update the object.

```
methods: {
    toggle(subNavItem, index) {
        this.$set(subNavItem, 'isSelected', !subNavItem.isSelected)
}
```

But now my v-if isn't watching for this change.

```
v-if="subNavItem.isEnabled"
```

Comment: isEnabled should be object with all keys, that you want to enable / disable independently.

Comment: @M1K1O, I believe they only display one lang at a time and `isEnabled` is supposed to mean `isSelected`. Ref question: you don't need to modify the structure of the languages. You can store the enabled one separately and have a computed property which retrieves the selected one from the `navItem`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu or is enabled could contain the ID what is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

```
<li
    v-for="(subNavItem, index) in navItem.children"
    :key="index"
    @click="toggle(subNavItem, navItem)"
>

methods: {
    toggle(subNavItem, navItem) {
        // uncheck all languages
        navItem.children.map(function(x) {
            x.isSelected = false;
        })
        // check language
        this.$set(subNavItem, 'isSelected', !subNavItem.isSelected)
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }
}
```